# Is it possible to change an NSTimer's userInfo?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer, foundation

I have an `NSTimer` that has an `NSNumber` in its `userInfo`

```
fireTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(fireTileAddingToColumn:) 
                                           userInfo:myNumber 
                                            repeats:YES];
```

After the `NSTimer` is created and has run a couple of times, I would like to be able to change the value of `myNumber` and have it reflect in `fireTileAddingToColumn:` I have not had any luck getting this to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always pass an object holding the userInfo to the timer:

```
@interface Holder
@property id data;
-(id) initWithData: (id) data;
@end

// implement it

Holder *holder = [[Holder alloc] initWithData:myNumber];
fireTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self
             selector:@selector(fireTileAddingToColumn:) holder
              repeats:YES];

[Holder setData: myNumber2];
```

and the data change will be reflected in the selector

Answer (score 3):

You're best off creating a new timer. If the class doesn't provide an interface for changing that attribute, then you should consider it private and read-only.

It's not even possible in this case to do the usual end run around that, using KVC:

```
[timer setValue:newNumber forKey:@"userInfo"];
```

since `NSTimer` is not KVC-compliant for that key.

Answer (score 2):

The userInfo property of an NSTimer isn't intended to be a general-purpose data storage facility.  It's there so that you can have some context go along with your timer, so that the target of the timer can distinguish one timer from another if multiple timers invoke the same action.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy people's mutable `userInfo`:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(fireTileAddingToColumn:) 
                                       userInfo:@{@"mutable": [@{@"key": <value>} mutableCopy] 
                                        repeats:YES];
```

And to access it:

```
timer.userInfo[@"mutable"][@"key"] = <newValue>;
```